# how to create a photo unique filename for isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm adding a Astronomy Picture of The Day to my Windows Phone Astronomy app, and I want to allow users to save the displayed photo to their media library. All of the examples I found show how to do this, but all of the filenames are hard coded and overwrite files that have the existing name. So I need a way to create a unique file name. How can I adjust this example to create a unique filename?

```
// Create a filename for JPEG file in isolated storage.

        String tempJPEG = "fl.jpg";

        // Create virtual store and file stream. Check for duplicate tempJPEG files.
        var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (store.FileExists(tempJPEG))
        {
            store.DeleteFile(tempJPEG);
        }

        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = store.CreateFile(tempJPEG);
        StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
        Uri uri = new Uri("fl.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
        sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

        BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
        bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you don't expect multiple saves per second

```
String tempJPEG = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss")+".jpg";
```

Or some variant of that.

Just one way.